# SQL Help- in rewriting a query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

How can we reduce the Execution time of the below query?

Need help in rewriting below SQL query in a more efficient way?

```
SELECT A.*, C.*, F.*, D.*
FROM TABLE1 A  INNER JOIN
     TABLE2 C
     ON A.CODE = C.CODE INNER JOIN
     TABLE3 D
     ON A.CODE = D.CODE INNER JOIN
     TABLE4 F
     ON A.CODE = F.CODE
WHERE D.IND1 = 'N' AND
      D.IND2 = 'N' AND
      D.EFF_DATE = (SELECT MAX(X.EFF_DATE)
                    FROM TABLE3 X
                    WHERE X.CODE = D.CODE AND X.EFF_DATE <= A.EFFECTIVE_DATE
                   ) AND
      F.EFF_DATE = (SELECT MAX(Z.EFF_DATE)
                    FROM TABLE4 Z
                    WHERE Z.DETAIL_CODE = F.DETAIL_CODE AND Z.EFF_DATE <= A.EFFECTIVE_DATE
                   )
```

Comment: I think you will get a faster and more efficient answer if you provide a sample dataset. Generally, people are using http://sqlfiddle.com/ to provide these sets.

Comment: You have provided no sample data, no execution plans, no data model, no explanation of the business rules, no metrics of data volumes or skew, no information regarding indexes, statistics, etc. In short there is no way we can give you any meaningful advice on rewriting this query.

Answer (score 0):

For performance, I would start with indexes on:

- `TABLE3(IND1, IND2, CODE, EFF_DATE)`
- `TABLE3(CODE, EFF_DATE)`
- `TABLE1(CODE, EFF_DATE)`
- `TABLE2(CODE)`
- `TABLE4(CODE)`
- `TABLE4(DETAIL_CODE, EFF_DATE)`

If you have performance issues, though, I suspect your code may be generating unexpected Cartesian products.  Debugging that requires much more information.  I might suggest asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find out where the bottlenecks in your query are -- i.e. sub-queries, joins -- that will give you a better idea of what to look at.  In the absence of that, take a look at:

- modify your column projections (i.e. A.*, C.*, F.*, D.*) to only return the columns you need
- look at table partitioning for the queries accessing rows based on DATE values (TABLE3.EFF_DATE, TABLE4.EFF_DATE) (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56partition-090450.html)
- look at adding materialized view(s) either on the entire query OR the sub-queries (https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views)
- look at statistic generation if the query plan is not optimal (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96533/stats.htm#26713)

If you can provide an EXPLAIN plan (or Oracle's equivalent), that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Note that because of the conditions on the two sub-queries all the records in your result will have `D.EFF_DATE <= A.EFFECTIVE_DATE` and `F.EFF_DATE <= A.EFFECTIVE_DATE`, so I would suggest to put those conditions in the `JOIN` clauses.

Secondly, analytic functions may give better performance than subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT      A.*,C.*,F.*,D.*,
              RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY D.CODE 
                           ORDER BY D.EFF_DATE DESC) AS D_RANK,
              RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY F.DETAIL_CODE 
                           ORDER BY F.EFF_DATE DESC) AS F_RANK
  FROM        TABLE1 A
  INNER JOIN  TABLE2 C
           ON A.CODE = C.CODE
  INNER JOIN  TABLE3 D
           ON A.CODE = D.CODE
          AND D.EFF_DATE <= A.EFFECTIVE_DATE
  INNER JOIN  TABLE4 F
           ON A.CODE = F.CODE
          AND F.EFF_DATE <= A.EFFECTIVE_DATE
  WHERE       D.IND1 = 'N'
          AND D.IND2 = 'N'
)
WHERE D_RANK = 1 AND F_RANK = 1
```

Evidently you need to have the right indexes to optimise the execution plan.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I have a mutlilple code and effective date pair (duplicates), how can I limit it to Only one record using rank?

Comment: In that case use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`. But your original query would correspond to using `rank`.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is the total number of columns your query returns, you seem to be selecting all the columns from 4 tables.

We found that our complex queries ran in under a second when selecting only a few columns but took orders of magnitude longer when selecting many columns.

Question why you need so many columns in your result set.